Searching for documents by sum of nested fields attribute
In elasticsearch index I have list of following documents:
{
  "id": 9653,
  "title": "dr",
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "work_experiences": [
    {
      "company": "Crazy Software",
      "start_date": "2020-12-01",
      "end_date": "2024-04-01",
      "duration": 40,
      "tiers": []
    },
    {
      "company": "Softcore",
      "start_date": "2018-05-01",
      "end_date": "2020-12-01",
      "duration": 31,
      "tiers": []
    },
    ...
  }

Each profile has multiple work experiences. I need to create dynamic query:
List all profiles that:
  were working in total at least 50 months in companies with wildcard match *name* in company name

In this case john doe will be found because he was working 40 monts at crazy SOFTware and 31 months at SOFTcore

Answer #2. Runtime Field Scripting
Your issue can be solved by searching via a runtime field and scripting
GET /durations/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "runtime_mappings": {
        "total_duration": {
            "type": "long",
            "script": {
                "source": """
                    List workExperiences = params['_source']['work_experiences'];

                    long totalDuration = 0;
                    for (def workExperience : workExperiences) {
                        totalDuration += workExperience.duration;
                    }

                    emit(totalDuration);
                """
            }
        }
    },
    "fields": [
        "total_duration", "id"
    ],
    "_source": false,
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "total_duration": {
                "gte": 50
            }
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "durations",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : 1.0,
                "fields" : {
                    "total_duration" : [
                        71
                    ],
                    "id" : [
                        9653
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }


Thanks, that is exactly what I needed, I was aware about aggregations but it doesn't fit my case, great job

how about filter by internals, for me it is important to have filter by tiers inside like sum up only if has "XYZ" in tiers: []

Answer #1. Pure Aggregations
I simplified your mapping
PUT /durations
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "work_experiences": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "duration": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

and create your document
    PUT /durations/_bulk
    {"create":{"_id":1}}
{"id":9653,"title":"dr","first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","work_experiences":[{"company":"Crazy Software","start_date":"2020-12-01","end_date":"2024-04-01","duration":40,"tiers":[]},{"company":"Softcore","start_date":"2018-05-01","end_date":"2020-12-01","duration":31,"tiers":[]}]}

Aggregation query
GET /durations/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
    "aggs": {
        "by_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "id"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "user_duration": {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "work_experiences"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "total_duration": {
                            "sum": {
                                "field": "work_experiences.duration"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "duration_filter": {
                    "bucket_selector": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                            "total_duration": "user_duration>total_duration"
                        },
                        "script": "params.total_duration > 50"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "aggregations" : {
        "by_id" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key" : 9653,
                    "doc_count" : 1,
                    "user_duration" : {
                        "doc_count" : 2,
                        "total_duration" : {
                            "value" : 71.0
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

See my similar answers

elasticsearch-sort-term-aggregation-by-sum-total-of-2-nested-term-aggregations
elasticsearch-function-score-query-on-a-nested-array


in your example we have just bucket, I need ids of those, also preferably in list of hits not aggregations

The key of the bucket is a user id. Check it
